# Layout Widgets For Print Qt

Tags: c++, qt, printing, qprinter

I am trying to print an invoice from Qt. I have stored all the information necessary for this but I do not know how to layout all the widgets and text for print I know that I have to use QPrinter and I think I may need to use QPageLayout. I need to print a QTableWidget at the bottom of the page and just some text at the top. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I am unsure how to move widgets and text on the page for printing. I think QPageLayout will help but i can not find information for how to use it and the Qt Docs are not very helpful for that.

Comment: QWidgets are not really meant for printing, and doing a print layout using widgets will be an uphill battle that's very easy to lose. You need to do things some other way.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how I may do this?

Comment: Use `QTextDocument`, or html and print from webkit, or do the layout yourself (paint directly on the painter).